# Edit WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have purchased and downloaded WordPress theme. Developer told he will customise it but he wants the downloaded file. Is there any way for Developer to edit the theme online without me actually sending the downloaded file.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why would you not want to send the developer the theme files?

Comment: Maybe he can get them and use them for free for his/her sites?

Comment: Yes, only concern being he using it for free.

Comment: Actually, that really happens. What you can do is install it in wordpress and let him work on wordpress

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to WordPress. How do I install WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

Ya it is possible.

WordPress contains two built-in editors that allow you to edit Theme files directly from within your browser. They are called the Theme Editor and Plugin Editor.

Access the Theme Editor from the `Administration > Appearance > Editor menu`
The Plugin Editor is located at `Administration > Plugins > Editor.`

Comment: "Appearance-> Editor" Or plugins- Editor where is this?

Comment: You want to login into your wordpress site, then left side there is this option ,
See this image for reference
https://community.1and1.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/wordpress-theme-editor-active.png

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this. Do we login to WordPress site after we place the files on hosting server?

Comment: Hi Arun, First extract  your theme and copy it to yoursite.com/wp-content/themes directory
Then this theme will appeare in theme section, like https://codex.wordpress.org/images/thumb/9/9a/themes.png/640px-themes.png

Just activate it and give to the developer.

Comment: You are welcome Arun, mark this answer solved then :)

Answer (score 0):

do you know how to install it in wordpress? You can install it there and let him work inside wordpress. You should also avoid full FTP access to your files

Comment: I don't know how to install in WordPress. Help!

Comment: Sure, first off, do you already have wordpress installed? and are you able to login?

Comment: No I don't have WordPress installed. How do I start?

Comment: oh ok..Do you already have a hosting account and domain provider?

Comment: It's fairly easy if you have cpanel access in your hosting provider

Comment: I'm planning to purchase the hosting now. I have the domain.

Comment: oh ok, once you purchase the hosting, by logging into cpanel, there is a install wizard for wordpress. Have you chosen a hosting provider? I recommend hostgator

Comment: If you are still about to buy a hostgator account, may I recommend my affiliate link? If that's ok with you :)

Comment: Yes sure. Please share the link.

Comment: Hi @ArunKumar have you got a hosting provider yet? Here's my affiliate link, as you've approved, but it's with ipage, another great service https://www.ipage.com/join/index.bml?AffID=863367

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would let the developer have the files to work with how he/she chooses to do so.  If you do not trust the developer to do the job he has been hired to do after sharing the files with him, I would simply find a developer that you DO trust.  Starting a working relationship with someone you do not trust is a recipe for disaster.

You will pay more for crippling the developer by forcing him to use tools/editors that are not worth his time, and you will damage the relationship by demonstrating a lack of trust on your end.

If I were you, I'd find someone I can trust, and have him install wordpress for you, customize the theme and help you set up hosting.  This way, you can work with him to perfect the content, give him the required assets, and do QA testing while he does the heavy lifting.

Comment: Editing tool vs editing downloaded file, which one is easier and less time consuming?

Comment: It's way easier to work with a project you can download to your development environment so you can use build tools, and your editor/IDE of choice.  Also, it will allow him to set up a local site (on his computer) that he can work on, without constantly breaking the live site that your customers/clients may be looking at while he is working on it.